# expected dense_43_input to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network

i'm trying to get into NN, and i was making the simplest model to show it in the university. But now i'm really bad in it and only learning.

I got an error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_43_input to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(500, input_shape=(3,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('linear'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=3, validation_split=0.3)
```

Predict:

```
t = np.array([-0.969308, 224.257508, 95.873082])
predict = model.predict(t)
```

The shape of the prediction is (3,).

What do i miss?

Answer (score 1):

Change your array to `np.array([[-0.969308, 224.257508, 95.873082]])`. If you do not add another dimension to your data then tf thinks you are asking to it to predict 3 inputs of 1 instead of 1 input of 3

Edit: to comment on the other answer, your output dimensions are fine as the model is definitely complaining about the inputs. The predict function expects an array of inputs

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you change the model.add(Dense(1)) to model.add(Dense(3))?

Comment: Maybe i'm not right, but the last layer is Dense(1) is for the output of one number, and the error is because of the input.